# LocalStorage login con Phonegap

Tags: php, login, cordova, phonegap

Estoy creando una app desde 0 con phonegap, tengo el login y el registro creado correctamente, conectado con la db utilizando javascript y php. Todo perfecto, pero por supuesto quiero que al iniciar la app recuerde que está logueado el usuario. El caso es que encontré un ejemplo por internet en el cual me basé y el cual pone este codigo javascript para enviar por ajax el login:

```
$("#login").click(function(){
var email=$("#email").val();
var password=$("#password").val();
var dataString="email="+email+"&password="+password+"&login=";
if($.trim(email).length>0 & $.trim(password).length>0)
{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: url,
data: dataString,
crossDomain: true,
cache: false,
beforeSend: function(){ $("#login").html('Connecting...');},
success: function(data){
if(data=="success")
{
localStorage.login="true";
localStorage.email=email;
window.location.href = "index.html";
}
else if(data="failed")
{
alert("Login error");
$("#login").html('Login');
}
}
});
}return false;
});
```

El caso es que al parecer define la variable del localstorage directamente, y luego para desloguear utiliza este codigo:

```
$("#logout").click(function(){
localStorage.login="false";
window.location.href = "login.html";
});
```

La duda se me plantea en que si se puede definir directamente el localStorage, ya que por ahí he leido que se utiliza alguna funcion como setlocal=(name,name). Y cosas del estilo, así que quería saber si está bien, y si se os ocurre otra forma de mantener el login, ya que me parece la mejor, y al parecer tendría que añadir la password, pero además cifrandola con un javascript tambien no? Ya que si no se guardaría en el telefono sin ningún tipo de cifrado.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Hola alex la forma correcta de trabajar con LocalStorage es acceder a sus funciones setItem(item, valor) y getItem(item) para modificar o agregar un valor y obtener un valor definido:

```js
var user = {
  name: 'julian'
}

LocalStorage.setItem( 'name', user ); //guardando el valor en el indice 'name'...

var name_recovered = LocalStorage.getItem('name'); //devuelve el valor 'julian' que guardamos previamente, si no existe devuelve undefined.

LocalStorage.removeItem('name'); //eliminamos el item que teniamos guardado.
```

Comment: Entonces debería de modificar: localStorage.login="true";
localStorage.email=email;                 por:    LocalStorage.setItem( 'login', true );   LocalStorage.setItem( 'email', email );  correcto?

Comment: Correcto, pruebalo y me cuentas como te fue...

Comment: Hola Julian! Te informo... Resulta que si se me registra, pero resulta que escribiendo localStorage.email = email; también se me registra O.o . Entonces mi duda, puedo utilizar la que yo te digo? Y además, como puedo mostrarla el localstorage en un h2 por ejemplo?

Comment: Hola alex, es posible que se pueda, pero definitivamente la mejor practica es hacer uso de las funciones destinadas para ese fin, una vez que obtengas el valor que quieres mostrar en el h2, debes indentificar ese h2 con jquery por ejemplo: $('.clase_de_mi_h2').html(valor);